# How can I migrate my .NET Framework WPF project to .NET Core?

Tags: wpf, .net-core

As we know,.net core 3.0 support WPF project now.


And now I want to migrate my .NET Framework WPF project to .NET Core.


I installed Visual Studio 2019 Preview 2.2 & .NET Core 3.0 Preview 2. However, it seems Visual Studio 2019 has no way to migrate old the WPF project to .NET Core. I googled and found nothing about this.


Is there any way for me to migrate it or I can only rewrite it all by .NET Core? Thank you.

Comment: .NET Core 3 is a *preview* that's only a couple of months old. It's WAY too early to migrate. Things *will* change and the tooling isn't complete yet.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Several of my friends are using .net core to coding WPF now. All of them said the WPF .net core version is stable so that I want to upgrade my project to .net core also.

Comment: They should probably read [Microsoft's announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2019/01/29/announcing-net-core-3-preview-2/) instead of assuming. Read the `Visual Studio Support` section : `The WPF and Windows Forms designer teams are continuing to work on an updated designer for .NET Core, which will be part of a Visual Studio 2019 Update.` If you want something relatively stable, wait for RC1 or RC2.

Comment: Also the [Visual Studio 2019 Preview 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2019/01/24/visual-studio-2019-preview-2-is-now-available/) announcement. Someone asks specifically about the designer in the comments. The answer : `It will still be some time until it is ready as we need to undergo a fairly large re-architecture to ensure stability`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OK, it seems I have to give up unless Microsoft publish this function.

Comment: No reason to but perhaps you should clarify what you want to do in the first place? You can start creating WPF applications now and check how they work. The *code* won't have a lot of differences. The project file formats though have changed with .NET Core (not just 3.0) so you can't use the original project file. `csproj` was greatly simplified and now you *don't* need to specify every single file, all `cs` files in the folder are compiled

Comment: As far as I understand, if I just change the old project csproj file as .NET Core standard then the project migrate successfully? Right?@PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: "You can start creating WPF applications now and check how they work. The code won't have a lot of differences." Thats not guaranteed. Net Core WPF is still in 'preview' it will inevitably change over time.

Comment: @RobertPerry OK, thank you very much.